# aws load balancer for non-https microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, load-balancing, amazon-elb

If I have a microservice that does not have http/https endpoints, and its sole purpose is to pull data from an ActiveMQ queue. It is possible to to set up a load balancer that doesn't require a http/https listener on the microservice?

Comment: on AWS there's a Network Load Balancer so you can proxy TCP packets to your service. Not sure for UDP

Answer (score 0):

From aws support:
"In this scenario, if you are hosting your services, which are responsible for pulling up data from Active MQ, on EC2 instances, you can make use Auto Scaling with the appropriate scaling policy. This will help you accomplish scaling up and down of the instances according to the load requirement or settings"

This is what I was looking for